# check validation of an expression with Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need in my code to verify the validity of an expression entered in a textbox, so I thought to Regex but my problem is that I do not get it.

So here is my expression: [3 Numbers]-[1 character Shift].[1 Number].

for example: 007-L.4

I try with this:

```
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("^[0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z].[O-9]$")
```

but it does not work

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors in your pattern:

```
^[0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z].[O-9]$
                  ^ ^
                  1 2
```

1. The `.` is a metacharacter which matches *any character*. You need to escape it to `\.` to match periods only,
2. Your range is not valid, since you wrote `O` (the letter) instead of `0` (the digit). :-)

Here's a the corrected pattern:

```
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("^[0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z]\.[0-9]$")
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/Khofqg))

Comment: You can write `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: @Olivier this is generally true but... in .NET `\d` is equivalent to `\p{N}` (any Unicode digit), not to `[0-9]`, that's why I left it alone.

Comment: if you want to use \d you have to add the ECMAScript option :  `Dim myRegex As New Regex("^\d{3}-[a-z]\.\d$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: Good to know. You can find the details here: [Character Classes in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx).